# The new extension is not visible in Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I noticed that from December 1 published extensions are not visible on the page https://chrome.google.com/webstore/ and google after such indexing is visible? Could it be some sort of algorithm update?

Or is it a temporary error?

Comment: I'm sorry but google forum did not get a response yet, I think that someone here will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Updating a web app's Chrome Web Store listing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/distribute-web-app#update_a_distributed_web_app) with these steps:

> 1. Open the web app script in the script editor.
> 2. Click **Publish > Register in Chrome Web Store**. Click **Edit store item**. This will bring up the **Edit Item** form you filled out during publication.
> 3. Make the changes you want to the description, graphic assets or other settings.
> 4. Click **Publish changes**.
> 5. Visit the [Chrome Web Store developer dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) to see the publication status of your web app. Note that the **publication process can take up to an hour to finish**. Once the "Status" column says "Published", your web app will be available in the store.

In addition to that, you may also check the [possible reasons](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq#faq-listing-09) why your item may not be showing in search.

If any of the given links doesn't help, I suggest that you [submit your issue](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/).